# Create parquet file with qualified name in databricks

Tags: parquet, databricks

I have to process some raw data files in csv with cleansing transformations and load as .parquet file in clenase layer. Raw layer file(csv) and Cleanse layer file should have same name.

But I cannot save the .parquet file with the given name, it is creating directory and underneath .parquet files are saved with random name. Please help how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how parquet files are designed to be, a collection of multiple row groups.
The name of your parquet is the folder the chunks of data will be saved under.
If you want a single file, you will have to use a different file format, and you will likely lose the parallelization capabilities offered by parquet for both read and write.